# What term can be used for people learning musical instruments?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What term can we use for a person who learns art, specifically musical instruments like a piano?

I know that the word "student" can be used in this situation and we can say "piano student" for example, but I wonder if there is a better word.

Comment: I recommend ear plugs.

Answer (score 1):

An ***aspiring instrumentalist***.

A ***budding instrumentalist***.

An ***instrumentalist in the making***.

From **oxforddictionaries.com**:

> **[instrumentalist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instrumentalist)** 
>   *NOUN*
>
> 1 A player of a musical instrument: *is the skilled pop **instrumentalist**
>   an endangered species?*
>
> **[aspiring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aspiring)** 
>   *ADJECTIVE* [ATTRIBUTIVE]
>
> Directing one’s hopes or ambitions towards becoming a specified type
>   of person: *an **aspiring** artist*
>
> **[budding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/budding#budding__5)** 
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> 1.2 (Of a person) beginning and showing signs of promise in a particular sphere:
>   ***budding*** young actors
>
> **[in the making](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/making)**
>
> In the process of developing or being made:
>   *a campaign that’s been two years **in the making***

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to satiate your requirement of it pertaining to music, but here are a few terms that fit otherwise.
**Novice**: *A person new to or inexperienced in a field or situation.*
**Neophyte**: *A person who is new to a subject, skill, or belief.*
**Rookie**: *A novice; tyro.*
**Aspiring**: *Directing one's hopes or ambitions toward becoming a specified type of person.*
**Up and coming**: *(Of a person beginning a particular activity or occupation) making good progress and likely to become successful.*
**Trainee**: *A person undergoing training.*

These are all simple responses, but I don't have any other suggestions.

Oxford American College Dictionary.